# wsHttpBinding not working in a WCF service selfhosted; SOAP-based bindings do work

Tags: wcf, rest, webhttpbinding

I have a simple WCF Service shown below.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string GetData(int value);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

The server Web.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttpEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehaviourDebug">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.
                     Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service name="Diws.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviourDebug">
            <endpoint
                address="/basicHttp"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="Diws.IService1"/>
            <endpoint
                address="/webHttp"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBehavior"
                contract="Diws.IService1"/>
            <endpoint
                address="/wsHttp"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="Diws.IService1"/>
            <endpoint
                address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The client is a console app whose App.config is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>

<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webHttpEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WsHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint
            address="http://localhost:50001/Service1.svc/basicHttp"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpEndpoint_IService1" />
        <endpoint
            address="http://localhost:50001/Service1.svc/webHttp"
            behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="WebHttpEndpoint_IService1" />
        <endpoint
            address="http://localhost:50001/Service1.svc/wsHttp"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="WsHttpEndpoint_IService1"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

And the client program is this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        String response = "";

        Service1Client basicHttpClient = new Service1Client("BasicHttpEndpoint_IService1");
        response = basicHttpClient.GetData(10);
        basicHttpClient.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(response);

        ///* Some communication exception
        Service1Client webHttpClient = new Service1Client("WebHttpEndpoint_IService1");
        response = webHttpClient.GetData(20);
        webHttpClient.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        //*/

        Service1Client wsHttpClient = new Service1Client("WsHttpEndpoint_IService1");
        response = wsHttpClient.GetData(30);
        wsHttpClient.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(response);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The basicHttpClient and the wsHttpClient work perfectly.  However, the webHttpClient throws the exception "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled, HResult=-2146233087, Message=Internal Server Error"

I cannot debug on the servers side as Visual Studio 2012 says
"Unable to automatically debug 'MyProject'. The remote procedure could not be debugged. This usually indicates that debugging has not been enabled on the server."

However, debugging is enabled.  I wasn't able to get any insights from using the SvcTraceViewer with diagnostics turned on.

My main interest is figuring out why the REST call using WebHttpBinding is failing, but help getting server side debugging working would be appreciated as well.  I'm debugging both the client and the server in VS2012 using multiple startup projects.  Localhost is the only server involved.

I understand that the REST endpoint won't show up in WcfTestClient since it provides no metadata exchange, but I expected to be able to call the service through that endpoint and I see no difference between my code and examples of calling RESTful WCF services.

Comment: Can you post on how your service contract looks like?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing a REST endpoint try making a HTTP POST request using a browser or HttpClient to the URL : $http://localhost:50001/Service1.svc/webHttp/GetData$. When you use webHttpClient as you do in your code to make a call to the service you are sending a SOAP request which a REST endpoint cannot process. I believe that's the reason your other two endpoints work fine but not this one.

Comment: I've changed the addresses, shown below.
'Host has been started
Endpoints
Address: http://localhost:50000/basicHttp
Binding: System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding
Contract: Diws.IService1

Address: http://localhost:50000/wsHttp
Binding: System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding
Contract: Diws.IService1

Address: http://localhost:50000/webHttp
Binding: System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding
Contract: Diws.IService1

Address: http://localhost:50000/mex
Binding: System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding
Contract: System.ServiceModel.Description.IMetadataExchange

Press [ENTER] to terminate.'

Comment: Also added '[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]' to service class.  When invoking service from web browser with URL 'http://localhost:50000/webHttp/GetData?value=40' I get the [ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/wcf-contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception).

Comment: I thought that the client's service proxy generated by Visual Studio would be able to handle both SOAP-based and REST-based endpoints as long as your client's configuration matches the server's configuration.  Is this not true?  Does the client proxy only handle SOAP-based endpoints and I should be using something like the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to access REST-based services exposed through wsHttpBinding endpoints?

Comment: I've also tried annotating the service interface with '[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]' or '[WebGet]'. Both produced the ContractFilter mismatch exception when poked by a browser or the internal error exception when poked by the client's proxy.

Comment: There is no wsdl for a REST endpoint. The Service1Client can be used for SOAP endpoints like basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding. To do a sample GET based service operation, change your annotation to WebGet. WebInvoke is for POST, PUT, Delete methods. Here is a quick example that I can point to : www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/freebookarticles/addisonwesley/2009aug25051629am/ProgrammableWeb/4.aspx. By doing so I was able to get your sample working on browsing to url: localhost:8080/Service/webHttp/GetData?value=123$