# Security mode= Transport throwing exception.

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0

netTcpBinding in my service app.config has security mode set to ‘None’and that is working fine. When I change it to the default mode of nettcpbinding i.e.Mode=Transport and clientCredentialType="Windows", I get following exception in GUI project while connecting to the this service

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.6982306'.

I viewed service trace in trace viewer and that showed the following error message: The message with To 'net.tcp://localhost:9200/MyService/mex/mex' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
if I create a new service with a nettcpendpoint having default transport security, that works fine.

If anybody has any idea about this, please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/wcf-contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception

Comment: Have you got both client and server configurations set to the same security mode?

Comment: try removing the mex endpoint from the config file. if you are still facing the issue post your configs and i will be able to give you a definite answer