# WCF service caching all requests

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to write WCF service in which one method will be catching all requests. Plan to host it within standalone executable. Here is the contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class Proxy
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "*", Method = "*")]
    public string Test(Stream input)
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Here is the hosting code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:2535/");
    var binding = new WebHttpBinding();

    var host = new ServiceHost(new Proxy(), uri);
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Proxy), binding, uri);
    host.Open();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But when I'm pointing my browser to the `localhost:2535` i just see information about service and fact that metadata is not enabled. And when I getting something like `localhost:2535/bla-bla-bla/` error rises:

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

I don't understand what I'm missing, to be frankly... Would be very grateful for helping me to get back on right track.

**EDIT:** Solved by explicitly adding `WebHttpBehavior` behavior to the endpoint. The resulting code become:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:2535/");
    var binding = new WebHttpBinding();

    var host = new ServiceHost(new Proxy(), uri);
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Proxy), binding, uri).Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    host.Open();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'm still looking for more detailed explanation why it's working that way...

Comment: Can you put up your service host web.config also.

Comment: Metadata is not enabled by default. That is an additional endpoint and behaviour.

Comment: Why do I need metadata if I don't plan to generate client from it?

Comment: @NickRyan I don't have any configuration file with my executable. Everything is done with via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add to your Endpoint's behaviour WebHttpBehavior, like this

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Proxy), binding, uri).Behaviours.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit odd that your `ServiceContract` attribute is defined directly on the class that implements your service. Usually you'd define this on the interface that defines the service. Example here:-
[MSDN ServiceContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx)

Comment: It is bad. But does it technically really matter? Does it not just only use reflection to parse the attributes?

Comment: I'm not sure, really you should have the method decorated with OperationContract as well. That could be the cause of your error. No service contract is 'claiming' your message. There is an SO article about this exception here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/wcf-contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception

Answer (score 0):

To enable metadata exchange you need to add `ServiceMetadataBehavior` just like that

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpGetUrl = new Uri(String.Format("{0}/mex", endpointUrl)) }; 
Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehaviour);
```

And then use localhost:2535/mex to retrieve the service metadata. If it succeeds have a look if your Test method is included in the metadata. If it fails try to configure [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to get more detailed and user friendly error messages.
Also make sure you marked you method with OperationContract attribute.

Hope it helps.