# ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7.5, wcf-binding

Here i am calling the method from the hosted RESTful service in my browser

```
https://eshop/LinkService/LinkService.svc/GetStudentObj
```

and getting the following error

```
The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)
```

Config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="LinkService.LinkService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="https" contract="LinkService.ILinkService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="https">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and

```
   public Student GetStudent()
        {
            Student stdObj = new Student
            {
                StudentName = "Bala",
                Age = 29,
                Mark = 95
            };
            return stdObj;

        }
```

and

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILinkService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetStudentObj", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Student GetStudent();
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: For what is worth, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31678625/1257607) may be useful

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add behaviour configuration in `<endpoint address />` tag

```
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="https" contract="LinkService.ILinkService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
```

Comment: This q and a indirectly helped me, so upvotes all around.