# Rewrite WCF binding from app.config to code

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, wcf-client, custom-binding

I try rewrite WCF custom binding from app.config to code.

**App.config**

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="cb">
    <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"
              authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport"
              requireDerivedKeys="true"
              includeTimestamp="true"
              messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">
      <issuedTokenParameters keyType="BearerKey"
                             tokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0">
        <additionalRequestParameters>
          <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
            <trust:TokenType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</trust:TokenType>
            <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
          </trust:SecondaryParameters>
        </additionalRequestParameters>
        <issuer address="xxx" />
      </issuedTokenParameters>
      <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
      <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
    </security>
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

**Code:**

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();

var issuedTokenParameters = new IssuedSecurityTokenParameters();
issuedTokenParameters.KeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
issuedTokenParameters.TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0";

XNamespace trust = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512";

var secondaryParameters = new XElement(trust + "SecondaryParameters",
                                       new XElement(trust + "TokenType") { Value = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0" },
                                       new XElement(trust + "KeyType") { Value = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer" });
issuedTokenParameters.AdditionalRequestParameters.Add(secondaryParameters.ToXmlElement());

issuedTokenParameters.IssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress("XXX");

var securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateIssuedTokenOverTransportBindingElement(issuedTokenParameters);

securityElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;
securityElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
securityElement.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;
securityElement.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;

binding.Elements.Add(securityElement);
binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement());
binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());

return binding;
```

Code binding is not good because when I call service I get error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter m
>   ismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and r
>   eceiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same co
>       ntract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Any advice? I can not find what is wrong or missing in code binding.

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for this error. Check this existing post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception)

Comment: I see two possible issues.  First, you're not setting the MessageVersion in this line:  `binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement());`; secondly, you're not setting the `useDerivedKeys` property (which is not available SecurityBindingElement but is on the SecurityElement`.