# The message with To 'http://tempuri.soatest.com/to/change_this' cannot be processed at the receiver

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a request from my REST client (WEB API- SendAysncRequest) using POSTMAN/SOA test tool and getting two confusing errors:

> The message with To 'http://tempuri.soatest.com/to/change_this'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch
>   at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree.

and

> The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an
>   AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the
>   sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

Can anyone provide assistance with this issue?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more information about your situation, such as the setup you're using, the values you're providing, or even better: some sample code :)

Comment: This is the generic solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding below soap header in the request

```
<wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://localhost/CustomerManagerWebSvcHost/CustomerManager.svc</wsa:To>
```