# xmlhttpRequest calling wcf-service ActionNotSupported

Tags: wcf, xmlhttprequest

I am calling a wcf-service like this:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:12525/ElasticServiceProxy.svc', true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
xmlhttp.send(soapBody);
```

The soapBody works if I put it in SoapUI and call the service. I get the correct answer. But in javascript-code it doesn't work.

I also added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header in Application_BeginRequest.

I also tried with axios (axios.post(...)) - didn't work.

I get this error: **The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher**

What do I miss?

thx a-x-i

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception) SO post lists out possible causes  for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved

In Javascript I added this:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("soapAction", "namespace/Interface/Operation");
```

In my wcf I had to add this in Application_BeginRequest:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "SoapAction");
```

So now my WCF works perfect :)

a-x-i