# Why does my WCF SOAP soapAction header change to match the custom domain?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have a WCF SOAP service hosted on an Azure App Service.  It has two custom domains attached, `service-abc.com` and `service-123.com` (as well as the default azure address of `service-abc.azurewebsites.net`)

In my WCF Service Contract, I have the SOAP Actions defined as follows, using the `service-abc.com` domain:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "https://service-abc.com/GetTodos", ReplyAction = "https://service-abc/GetTodos")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
    [LegacyFormatMessage]
    Task<GetTodosResponse> GetTodos(GetTodosRequest request);
```

When I ask for the wsdl for this service, the soapAction values change to match the domain.

Eg:

`GET https://service-abc.azurewebsites.net/?wsdl` will return:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetTodos">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://service-abc.azurewebsites.net/GetTodos" style="document"/>
```

`GET https://service-abc.com/?wsdl` will return:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetTodos">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://service-abc.com/GetTodos" style="document"/>
```

`GET https://service-123.com/?wsdl` will return:

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetTodos">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://service-123.com/GetTodos" style="document"/>
```

But calling the SOAP service using those any of those soapActions apart from (`https://service-abc.com/GetTodos`) results in the error:

```
The message with Action 'https://service-123.com/GetTodos' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None). in <source stack trace>
```

because the Action supplied `https://service-123/GetTodos` does not match the Action defined in the contract `https://service-abc.com/GetTodos`

So the question is, can I stop the wsdl generating with the custom domain in the soapActions and just stay as the soapActions defined in the contract?  IE, can the wsdl just return

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetTodos">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://service-abc.com/GetTodos" style="document"/>
```

regardless of which domain the request is made on?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487791/contractfilter-mismatch-at-the-endpointdispatcher-exception). It describes the situation similar to yours.